# What exactly does a capacitor and resistor in these earphones do and how do they change the impedance/phase response?

Tags: audio

There is a headphone with different models for different uses, ER4B for Binaural music (High frequency boost if you wanna call it that), ER4S (normal high frequency for stereo) and ER4P (for portable use, aka low impedance).

Here is the scheme of the er4b and er4b, of course the frequency response if different but I wanna know what exactly happens. Difference on magnitude response from top to left er4b green, er4s blue and er4p red:

[image]

Here is the ER4B and ER4S impedance and phase curves and as you can see are totally different:

[image]

And I find this "universal scheme" for the three models but I don't know how to read it correctly:

[image]

Comment: Angelo Lorenzoni - Hi, Please note that when a post copies or adapts material (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) from elsewhere, that content must be [correctly referenced](/help/referencing). For online content, the source webpage / PDF / video etc. should be named & linked as a minimum (see the rule about references for offline books / articles). Therefore please [edit] your question to add the appropriate source reference(s) (source name & link) for each image & remember to include references in future. (As you are new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as site rules differ from forums).

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to actually be:

> Idk how to read it correctly

"Idk" apparently means "I don't know"

The switch (SW) will connect to terminal 4P, 4S, or 4B, depending on the position of the switch.  From that, we see in position 4P, the 73 ohm resistor is shorted out:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fucM5B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In position 4S the switch goes nowhere, so the two resistors are left in the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjKYkA.png)</sup>

In position 4B, the 680 nF capacitor, which was unconnected until now, is placed across the 73 ohm resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRW9Yx.png)</sup>

Comment: And how exactly it changes the phase and impedance curve?

Comment: @AngeloLorenzoni To know how it changes the phase & impedance across the earphone, you need to know the complex impedance of the earphone versus frequency. With that, you can solve it using a SPICE simulator or a spreadsheet.